# material-ui container doesn't work with custom breakpoints on typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm using material-ui and typescript in my learning project. And I came across a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I use custom breakpoints in material-ui theme.

```
import { createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  breakpoints: {
    values: {
      small: 480,
      mobile: 640,
      tablet: 960,
      laptop: 1280,
      desktop: 1440,
    },
  },
});

export { theme };
```

And create new file BreakpointsOptions.d.ts

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { BreakpointOverrides } from '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints';

declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints' {
  interface BreakpointOverrides {
    /* ------------------------------------- */
    /*      Removes defaults breakpoint      */
    /* ------------------------------------- */
    xs: false;
    sm: false;
    md: false;
    lg: false;
    xl: false;

    /* ------------------------------------- */
    /*            Adds new breakpoint        */
    /* ------------------------------------- */
    small: true;
    mobile: true;
    tablet: true;
    laptop: true;
    desktop: true;
  }
}
```

And now I want to use Container from material-ui.

```
import React, { FC } from 'react';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';

type PropTypes = {
  component: string;
  children: NonNullable<React.ReactNode>;
  className?: string;
};

export const MaxWidthContainer: FC<PropTypes> = (props: PropTypes) => {
  const { component, children, className } = props;

  return (
    <Container component={component} maxWidth="desktop" className={className}>
      {children}
    </Container>
  );
};
```

But I get the error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtQdR.png)

So, how can I fix this error without modifying the files in the folder "node_modules" ?

Answer (score 0):

From reading the material-ui docs, I think the `Container` components `maxWidth` attribute only accepts the following values:

```
  'lg'
| 'md'
| 'sm'
| 'xl'
| 'xs'
| false
```

You've set `maxWidth` as `desktop`, which is throwing that error.

But i understand that your aim is to set a custom breakpoint such as `desktop`.

From the docs this is how you set up custom breakpoints in typescript for material-ui, you can create a `Theme.tsx` file which is scoped within your `tsconfig`:

```js
import {
    createMuiTheme
} from '@material-ui/core/styles'
import {
    BreakpointOverrides
} from "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints"

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createBreakpoints" {
    interface BreakpointOverrides {
        /* ------------------------------------- */
        /*      Removes defaults breakpoint      */
        /* ------------------------------------- */
        xs: false;
        sm: false;
        md: false;
        lg: false;
        xl: false;
        
        /* ------------------------------------- */
        /*            Adds new breakpoint        */
        /* ------------------------------------- */
        small: true;
        mobile: true;
        tablet: true;
        laptop: true;
        desktop: true;
    }
}


declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme' {
    interface Theme {
        appDrawer: {
            width: React.CSSProperties['width']
            breakpoint: BreakpointOverrides
        }
    }
    // allow configuration using `createMuiTheme`
    interface ThemeOptions {
        appDrawer ? : {
            width ? : React.CSSProperties['width']
            breakpoint ? : BreakpointOverrides
        }
    }
}

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
    breakpoints: {
        values: {
            small: 480,
            mobile: 640,
            tablet: 960,
            laptop: 1280,
            desktop: 1440,
        }
    },
})
```

Also please verify the it's only the linter warnings in editor that are persisting. Like try running the app and see if the error is still thrown or not.